# Table needs to be scraped with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

There is table that needs to be scraped with scrapy.  The data in the the following format:

```
<table>

<tr class="colhead">
<td width="170">MON, NOV 11</td>
<td width="80">Item</td>
<td width="60" align="center"></td>
<td width="210">Item</td>
<td width="220">Item</td>
</tr>

<tr class="oddrow">
<td> Item </a></td>
<td> Item </td>
<td align="center"> Item </td>
<td></td>
<td> Item </td>
</tr>

<tr class="evenrow">
<td> Item </a></td>
<td> Item </td>
<td align="center"> Item </td>
<td></td>
<td> Item </td>
</tr>


</table>
```

I do get full list of items by

```
items = hxs.select('//table[@class="tablehd"]//td//text()').extract()
```

How would you split them to each item and then assign data td1 - td5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) shell examples, you should first grab the `<tr>` elements, then grab the `<td>` from those, something like this:

```
rows = hxs.select('//tr')
for row in rows:
    print row.select('td/text()').extract()
```

`rows` will be a list of `HtmlXPathSelector` objects which you iterate through, then extract the text from every `<td>` for the current `<tr>`.

`row.select('td/text()').extract()` will be a list containing the text of every cell for a given row:

```
[u'MON, NOV 11', u'Item', u'Item', u'Item']
[u' Item ', u' Item ', u' Item ', u' Item ']
[u' Item ', u' Item ', u' Item ', u' Item ']
```

Comment: thanks.. it works now.. had to replace the rows..